# I am getting an runtime error while logging

Tags: python, class, oop, logging

I am trying to try add an logger function for logging some basic messages but I is giving me an runtime error. The runtime error is occurring for all combination of the logging format. I believe the error is in formatting of asctimer but after removing that also the error is still there. please help me figuring out this issue. The error is shown below:

--- Logging error ---

```
KeyError: 'asctimer'
 %(asctimer)s%(levelname)s%(message)s
 %(levelname)s%(message)s
 %(levelname)s%(message)s
 %(levelname)s%(message)s
```

```
The code I am using is:
```

```
import os
import logging as lg
lg.basicConfig(filename ='dataclass.log' ,level = lg.DEBUG)
#console_log = lg.StreamHandler()
#console_log.setLevel(lg.INFO)
#lg.getLogger('').addHandler(console_log)
mapper = lg.getLogger('dataclass.mapping')
fileopen = lg.getLogger('dataclass.fileopen')
fileread = lg.getLogger('dataclass.fileread')
class data:
    
    
    def __init__(self,filename,filetype,date,size):
        try: 
         self.filename = filename
         self.filetype = filetype
         self.data = data
         self.size = size
         self.fl_type = self.mapping_file()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    def mapping_file(self):
        fl_type = []
        if(type(self.filename)== list):
            for j,i in zip(self.filename,self.filetype):
                if(type(j) != str):
                    self.Logger1('filename not string','mapper')
                    raise Exception('filename not a string')
                elif(i == 'text'):
                    self.Logger1('text file found','mapper')
                    fl_type.append('.txt')
                elif(i == 'image'):
                    self.Logger1('image file found','mapper')
                    fl_type.append('.jpg')
                elif(i == 'audio mp3'):
                    self.Logger1('audio file found','mapper')
                    fl_type.append('.mp3')
                else:
                    print('file type not supported')
                    self.Logger1('file type not found','mapper')
                    raise Exception("File type not supported")
        else:
                if(type(self.filetype) != str):
                    self.Logger1('filename not string','mapper')
                    raise Exception('filename not a string')
                elif(self.filetype == 'text'):
                    self.Logger1('text file found','mapper')
                    fl_type.append('.txt')
                elif(self.filetype == 'image'):
                    self.Logger1('image file found','mapper')
                    fl_type.append('.jpg')
                elif(self.filetype == 'audio mp3'):
                    self.Logger1('file type not found','mapper')
                    fl_type.append('.mp3')
                else:
                    print('file type not supported')
                    self.Logger1('file type not found','mapper')
                    raise Exception("File type not supported")
        return fl_type

    def file_open(self):
      try:
        self.file_var = []
        if(type(self.filename)== list):
            
            for i,j in zip(self.filename,self.fl_type):
                if(os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+i+j)):
                    self.file_var.append(open(i+j, 'r'))
                    self.Logger1(i+j+'file opened', 'fileopen')
                else:
                    self.file_var.append(open(i+j, 'w+'))
                    self.Logger1(i+j+'file opened', 'fileopen')
        else:
                if(os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+self.filename+self.fl_type[0])):
                   self.file_var.append(open(self.filename+self.fl_type[0], 'r'))
                   self.Logger1(self.filename+self.fl_type[0]+'file opened', 'fileopen')
                else:
                   self.file_var.append(open(self.filename+self.fl_type[0],'w+'))
                   self.Logger1(self.filename+self.fl_type[0]+'file opened', 'fileopen')
      except Exception as e:
          print(e)
          self.Logger1('error opening file', 'fileopen')
          for i in self.file_var:
              i.close()
    def file_read(self):
         if(type(self.filename)== list):
            for i in  self.file_var:
                i.read()
                self.Logger1(i.name+' read', 'fileread')
         else:
                self.file_var[0].read()
                self.Logger1(self.file_var[0].name+' read', 'fileread')
    def file_close(self):
         if(type(self.filename)== list):
            for i in  self.file_var:
                i.close()
         else:
               self.file_var[0].close()
    def Logger1(self,msg,fun):
        if(fun == 'mapper'):
            mapper.info(msg)
        elif(fun == 'fileopen'):
            fileopen.info(msg)
        elif(fun == 'fileread'):
            fileread.info(msg)
```

These are the execution lines:

```
     data1 = data(['a1','b1','c1'],['carbon','image','text'],['21-08-2022','21-08-2022','21-08-2022'],[0,0,0])
     data1.file_open()
     data1.file_read()
     data1.file_close()
```

No loggin file is being created as well.

Comment: well, It worked for me. At least partially. The log file was created and logged something. I am wondering why you use `self.Logger1(msg, 'mapper')` instead of direct loggers you created: `mapper.info(msg)`. Also you do not log exceptions but you catch them and print

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably caused because you're using `%(asctimer)s` for some reason - it should be `%(asctime)s`. You don't mention what format string you use, but it's what the error message shows. Change that, and if the error still occurs, provide *all* relevant information (for example, this time you don't show the full configuration used) and perhaps come up with a minimal reproducible code sample which shows the problem.